# editing array values VBA -- using Instr & Split -- Date output eccentricities

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Have a 2d Array, need to search through one of the columns finding a string and deleting everything after it.

I have a list of dates, but the format it is currently in has a long Time value
after the date ending in 2019. I would like to find and replace 2019 + time
with just 2019.

**Edit**  code

The date isn't stored as a date, for all intents and purposes it's a string that looks something like "****#### 2019 ######"   and I am just looking for a method to remove everything after a value, (2019) . 
Right now, it steps through it all nicely checks array value by value
but doesn't actually change anything.
**Edit2** 
Found workable solution using Instr & Split functions.
BUT the weirdest bug crept in, 
some dates appear fine in debug.print 
eg : 11/06/2019  BUT after printing to a range   06/11/2019
     13/06/2019                                  13/06/2019
Even if the format of the destination is pre-defined

Public Sub PrintArray(Data As Variant, Cl As Range)
    Cl.Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)) = Data
End Sub
Private Sub Test()

```
Dim Name_col As Integer
Dim Date_col As Integer
Dim Hours_col As Integer
Dim Department_col As Integer
Dim Data_row As Integer

Name_col = 1
Date_col = 2
Hours_col = 3
Department_col = 4
Data_row = 2

Dim i As Integer
Dim zom As Integer

Dim DirArray As Variant
Dim col As Integer

Dim LString As String
Dim LArray() As String

zom = 0
i = 2
col = 2


Dim X As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    i = i + 1
    zom = zom + 1
Loop
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True



NumberOfZombies = zom

Debug.Print "Number of zombies" & NumberOfZombies
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
DirArray = Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(Data_row, Name_col), Cells(zom, Department_col)).Value


For rw = LBound(DirArray) To UBound(DirArray)
    For col = LBound(DirArray) To UBound(DirArray, 2)


     LString = DirArray(rw, col)
     If InStr(LString, "2019") > 0 Then
     LArray = Split(LString)
     Debug.Print LArray(0)
     DirArray(rw, col) = LArray(0)
     End If
     Debug.Print DirArray(rw, col)
    Next
Next

PrintArray DirArray, Sheets("Sheet3").[A1]
```

End Sub

Comment: If your array is getting the value from a range, you don't need to do this through your array. If you do a `find and replace` (can be done with VBA) where find value is: **" *"** (NOTE: the space before the `*` character) and no value in replace, it will remove time from your range and leave the date

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` turned on?  There are a **lot** of variables in your code that you do not `Dim`, such as `data_ws, ows, NumRows, NumberOfZombies, tofind, toreplace, rw, col, a(), b()` - if these are not defined, then defined them.  If they *are* defined, then please include the definitions.  Otherwise, this is not a [mcve]

Comment: If the array holds Date types on that column you could just do this `Data(i, 2) = Year(Data(i, 2))`

Comment: @Damian The wording seems more to me like the contents are `26/06/2019 01:23`, and OP just wants `26/06/2019`.  So, perhaps `Data(i, 2) = Int(Data(i, 2))` instead?

Comment: True that @Chronocidal but that should be formated, or else it will print the date number for excel, right?

Comment: @Damian I think the actual issue would be the opposite:  If the content is string, then you need to `CDate` before you can `Int`.  But, to be extra-safe `Data(i, 2) = Format(Int(cDate(Data(i, 2))),"dd/mm/yyyy")`?  xD

Comment: @Zac the copied range to sheet is a prototyping step, so i had a copy of the test data to array 
actual data has thousands of entries and find and replace is a bit processor intensive.